# Platform-independent programmming with Java native code or C++ (QT, WxWidgets etc.)

Tags: java, c++, cross-platform, platform-independent

I am asking myself if it would be easier and more flexible to program a multiplatform application in Java and compile it to native binaries (the way Eclipse was written) or to use a cross-platform C++ framework like QT. Where are the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Eclipse is not compiled to native binaries; it consists of compiled Java classes. Part of it (SWT) needs native libraries, but those were written in C or C++.

Answer (score 2):

You will find less platform specific problems with Java, but:

- Some less commons platforms have C++ compilers/toolkits available but no JRE.
- With C/C++ you can usually access all native resources. With Java that is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your preferences. If you have much experience with C++, then stay to it. Platform-independence alone is not an argument, as Qt does an excellent job on guaranteeing platform-independent code and everybody can recompile a program on another system (that's actually what you want to do with your Java programs, too).

Answer (score 0):

I would just let the JVM do the compiling to native code.

You might assume its better to pre-compile it but for 98% of the time its not, it just harder and more complicated.

Comment: But precompiled Java runs faster, because the Java VM doesn't have to parse the code anymore.

Comment: @good-ingredient Actually it should run slower because the Hotspot-Compiler has all the runtime information the compiler doesn't have if you precompile, allowing more aggressive optimizations.

Comment: The JVM can compile code based on how it is actually used, not just a static analysis at compile time. This can make the start time slower but makes the code faster.

Comment: @good_ingredient that only speeds up the startup which is good for short running programs. The jit compiler can inline virtual method calls and optimize branching based on runtime information and recompile if an optimisation becomes invalid - good for anything running longer.